# Recursively remove adjacent duplicate from ArrayList of integers, without removing both

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I am writing a method to remove an adjacent duplicate value in an ArrayList of Integer.

```
public static void remove2InARow(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (list.get(i) == list.get(i+1)) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

If you passed in `[3,4,3,3]` as a parameter, the output would be `[3,4,3]`.

This implementation becomes problematic when the same value is repeated more than 2 times. For example, `[1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 1, 2]` becomes `[1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 2]` when it should be `[1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 1, 2]`. Similarly, `[n, ..., n]` should become `[n]`.

Is there a way to adapt my implementation to be recursive? Does it even *need* to be recursive?

Comment: Without even looking at the specifics, working backwards on a list you are modifying often will make the problem significantly easier.

Comment: Use `.equals()` to compare objects, not `==`.

Comment: Definitely agree with working backwards. Your for-loop should start at the last index and compare with the element at index i - 1. If they are the same, remove the current element from the list.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly does not need to be recursive!

The source of your problem is that removing elements from a collection while iterating over it can lead to some unexpected behaviour, try not to touch the list while iterating over it, then once you're done - remove the elements you need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public static void remove2InARow(ArrayList<Integer> list) {;

list= list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);

}
```

Maybe it'll help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void remove2InARow(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (list.get(i) == list.get(i+1)) {
            list.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: What should be the output for [6,6,6,6] ?